# Apply a CSS rule for a specific button that belongs to a class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, meteor

I have for example a web page that displays blog posts. Each blog posts has a 'comment' button and a 'like' button. When the user likes a post I want to apply a CSS style for that particular button. I have tried in many ways for example using "getElementsByClassName" to get the class of the button but it applies the rule for all the buttons. So if I have 5 blog posts all of them appear to be liked when I just like one of them. This is my JS code:

```
Template.post.events({
"click .like":function(event) {
 var likeButton1=document.getElementsByClassName('like');
 $(likeButton1).addClass('likeClick');
 var nrLikes=parseInt(this.likes);
 blogPosts.update(
   this._id,{
     $set:{"likes":nrLikes+1}
  }
);
}
});
```

And this is my html code:

```
<input class="like" type="submit" name="like" value="Like"/>
```

Basically I need the instance of that particular clicked button, how do I do this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try changing `$(likeButton1).addClass('likeClick');` to `$(this).addClass('likeClick');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this jQuery Code

```
 $('.class_name').each(function () {
       $(this).addClass('likeClick');
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementsByClassName` returns a HTMLCollection. You can iterate over this collection and use array methods by doing

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(HTMLCollection,callBackFunction)
```

Inside the callback function you can add an event listener to add the class on the element on click on it.

Below is a snippet which may be useful.
`classList.add` will add a new class to the existing element

```js
var likeButton1 = document.getElementsByClassName('like');
Array.prototype.forEach.call(likeButton1, function(el) {
  el.addEventListener('click', function() {

    this.classList.add('likeClick')
  })
});
```

```css
.likeClick {
  color: green
}
```

```html
<input class="like" type="submit" name="like" value="Like" />
<input class="like" type="submit" name="like" value="Like" />
<input class="like" type="submit" name="like" value="Like" />
<input class="like" type="submit" name="like" value="Like" />
<input class="like" type="submit" name="like" value="Like" />
<input class="like" type="submit" name="like" value="Like" />
<input class="like" type="submit" name="like" value="Like" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of selecting all the elements with the class `like`, try targetng the specific element that received the click event (using the `event` object you're passing into your "click . like" handler). This assumes the `event` in this case represents an `event` object that has a `target` property, of course.

```
var likeButton1= event.target; // this will be the element that received the `click`
$(likeButton1).addClass('likeClick');
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to use a CSS psuedo class. That is how you can style a button that has been clicked or visited. This can all be done in your css file.

*Example css file:*

```
input .like {
  (some css styling)
}

input .like:visited {
  (different css styling)
}
```

You can also use link, hover, and active psuedo classes. Here's the reference:

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_classes.asp